# www.example.com is not openning while example.com is working fine how to resolve it?

Tags: dns, web-hosting, no-www

when i am trying to access my domain with www it shows an error like  "This site can’t be reached
www.sustainabletourism.co.in’s server IP address could not be found.
Search Google for sustainable tourism co
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

and working with out wwww.

all dns records are set correctly

plz help me

thanx

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned DNS is configured corrent, than its is most probably due to wrong setup of virtual host for web server. Depending of the web server in use(eg. Apache or nginx or some other) you can correct this.

In the server alias, you need to add both www and without www of your domain.